# Reading old data in Spark with backward compatible schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I already have some older data stored in parquet with a schema represented by

```
case class A(name: String)
```

I'd like to add a new non-mandatory field in

```
case class B(name: String, age: Option[Int])
```

and read in both the old and new data to the same `DataFrame`. Each time I'm trying to read the data with `spark.read.parquet("test_path").as[B].collect()`, I'm getting the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`age`' given input columns: [name];

Is there a way to specify a backward compatible schema for all of my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to read older data with a backward compatible schema, it's not enough to specify the new `Encoder`, you have to manually specify a `StructType` for the `DataSet`, and do not let Spark infer it based on either the . This way there isn't going to have missing fields during the conversion into a `DataFrame`:

`spark.read.schema(Encoders.product[B].schema).parquet("test").as[B].collect()`